# Moment Converting Date to Local Time?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, momentjs

I have a Kendo UI MVC grid on a page. In this grid are three date columns. The dates (no time value) are stored in the database as local time (not UTC). These columns are defined in the grid as follows:

```
            columns.Bound(p => p.CloseoutDate).ClientTemplate("#= moment(CloseoutDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY') #").Width(120);
            columns.Bound(p => p.BeginDate).Title("Begin Date").ClientTemplate("#= moment(BeginDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY') #").Width(110);
            columns.Bound(p => p.EndDate).Title("End Date").ClientTemplate("#= moment(EndDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY') #").Width(110);
```

You can see I'm using moment.js to do my date formatting. However, it seems that moment is assuming these dates are UTC dates and converting them to local time. When the grid is displayed, the dates look as follows:
[image]

All these dates are off by one day. For example, the first row should be 1/15/2010, 1/1/2010, 1/15/2010. Is this normal moment behavior, and can it be changed?

Also, CloseoutDate, BeginDate and EndDate are actual C# datetime values. In the SQL Server database they are stored as dates.

Comment: Maybe try moving `format` into the `moment(DateField)` e.g. `moment(CloseoutDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')`. Source from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37278220/6224482).

Comment: Which is the value of `CloseoutDate`, `BeginDate` and`EndDate`? Are these values strings? In this case you can use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: @VincenzoC - CloseoutDate, BeginDate and EndDate are actual C# datetime values. In the database they are stored as dates.

Comment: @RandyMinder unfortunately I don't know enough about C#, what is passed to moment constructor?

Comment: @VincenzoC is there any difference between your comment and mine?

Comment: @Sandman they are quite similar, but my main goal was to know about variables' type from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue:

```
            columns.Bound(p => p.CloseoutDate).ClientTemplate("#= moment.utc(CloseoutDate,'MM/DD/YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY') #").Width(120);
            columns.Bound(p => p.BeginDate).Title("Begin Date").ClientTemplate("#= moment.utc(BeginDate,'MM/DD/YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY') #").Width(120);
            columns.Bound(p => p.EndDate).Title("End Date").ClientTemplate("#= moment.utc(EndDate,'MM/DD/YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY') #").Width(120);
```

Basically using the moment library and the UTC constructor.

Answer (score -1):

u can format date in column

```
{ field: "beginDate", title: "Begin Date", format: "{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}",parseFormats: "{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}"}
```

Comment: 1) I don't have a time component on these dates. 2) How would this prevent dates from getting converted to local time? 3) How would I pass this in to my current statements shown in the original post?

Comment: what is response from client side?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: yes, sorry, i was confusing. Do you communicate to database directly or you have some web servis?

Comment: This is an MVC app. So a call is being made to an MVC controller method which passes data to the client via an AJAX call.